# Android Studio cannot be opened after update to 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

On Mac Book Pro 2011, Mac OS 10.11.6, when trying to open Android Studio, now I get this message: "The application ... cannot be opened."

Comment: Where to find the logs: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: @MorrisonChang There are still no entries for AndroidStudio3.0. And trying to open it does not change any 2.3 logs. I cannot find any crash logs anywhere.

Comment: Try a fresh install and do not use cache/ settings from existing version. It would help

Comment: And you went into the Mac settings -> Security and enabled non-Apple store apps to run, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do not update/patch Android Studio from the dialogs showing up in the application, but download the new version separately from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html, override the app while importing your settings from the previous version.

If you use Java 8 features in your project, you have to remove the retrolambda dependency first: http://codevscolor.com/2017/08/java-8-android-studio-tutorial-1/